# Cross Forest Public Folder Migration, Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 SP1

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, migration, cross-domain, active-directory

I'm doing a migration from Exchange 2003 SP2 to Exchange 2010 SP1, cross-forest.

I have mostly everything else sorted, but this company makes extensive use of Public Folders, and my google-fu is failing me here.

How do I migrate the public folders?
I found a vague description of one process here: http://blog.sembee.co.uk/post/Cross-Forest-Public-Folder-Migration.aspx

However I'm not sure if that is a 'good' process, and I don't know how you would do that using an outlook rule.   Also, i'm yet to try out Outlook 2010 :)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting the public folders to PST and doing it that way.

Unfortunately I could not come up with a better solution.